# Most RAM efficient way to reference integer constants in C

Tags: c, performance, memory, constants

I am working on a application for micro-controller/sensor devices.  My question is, what is the most memory efficient way to store named constants in such a way they can be referenced from other locations?  Ideally, we would want to avoid storing the same value in either RAM/ROM over and over again.  The obvious choices are

1. `#define CONSTANT 0`
2. `extern int CONSTANT = 0;`
3. `const int CONSTANT = 0;`
4. (Some mix of 3. and 4.)
5. `enum ...` (for multiple constants)

Again, I want to prevent storing these values over and over again in memory.  So if I have

```
if (CONSTANT == x)
{
    ...
}
...
y = CONSTANT;
```

the goal would be to prevent CONSTANT being stored twice.  Perhaps this is a compiler optimization issue, or what I am thinking is not possible since you would end up having to store a pointer and reading from it, making it *less* efficient than storing multiple copies in the first place.

Comment: An `enum` in a header?

Comment: With a good optimizing compiler you usually do not need to care, just select prefer-space-over-speed optimization flag.

Comment: `enum` seemed like most reasonable choice to me, but I am no compiler guru.  Coworker suggested `extern` approach, but I am suspicious...

Comment: For single integer values, this is highly unlikely to make much of a difference -- you're either going to be loading it from memory each time (e.g. `mov [global_var], %eax` in x86) or storing it as an immediate value in the instruction (e.g. `mov $1234, %eax`).

Comment: What target processor, what software tools?

Comment: You can largely answer this yourself by writing sample code for the various scenarios (including referring to the same constant from sources compiled into separate object modules) and examining the assembly and the final linked machine code that is produced. The answers are completely dependent on the tools you are using and the target platform; nobody can give you definite answers without this information.

Comment: in my experience it's more important to avoid branching than to care about this details, also less branching means less fetching and less frequent access to memory which is your final goal if I understand this correctly.

Comment: @Eric We are targeting many various microcontrollers and sensors.  Currently the compiled binary is way too big, and as noted above, a conversation between myself and a coworker sparked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both `#define` and `enum` the compiler will be able to code the integer constant into the generated instructions. It may also be able to do it with `const int` but that depends on the optimization capabilities of your compiler. The `extern` will almost always need to reference an address, which means the value will be somewhere else taking up memory.

Yes, the constant will be stored more than once, but that's preferable to a *pointer* to the constant being stored more than once.

Comment: So, to be clear, if the value is in memory via `const int`, instead of encoding the value into the instruction, we encode a memory address as part the of instruction instead, right?

Comment: “Will be able” should be “might be able” or “often is able, depending on the target processor”. Another factor is whether the linker does constant consolidation.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted yourself, storing an integer constant in *data* region of memory provides no memory savings when the size of the constant is smaller or equal to the size of memory address. This is because any machine instruction that refers to that stored constant will have to store its address. Size of `int` objects is usually smaller or equal to the size of machine address. For this reason, for `int` constants it makes more sense to embed them directly into machine instructions instead of storing them in *data* region.

If we interpret the specification of C language in the most literal way, that would mean that you'll have to use `#define` or `enum` - only these C language constructs can formally produce true constants. Of course, nothing prevents a C compiler to optimize the code and treat `[static] const int` objects as true constants as well, even though they are not recognized as such by the formal definition of the language. You have to test your compiler and see if it does that or not.

An `extern const int` object declared in some translation unit without an initializer cannot be embedded into machine instructions in that translation unit, which means that `extern const int` will not work well for this purpose (unless your compiler is capable of global optimizations).

Comment: These blanket statements do not apply to all processors. Also, a program can group constants together, set a pointer to the middle of them, and refer to all of them with small offsets from the pointer, thus using, on average, less space to address the constants than an whole address requires. And a processor architecture might have different size immediate fields available for offsets than other constants, or might have special instructions to assist in forming constants over multiple instructions.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: These "blanket" statements are in reality as non-blanket as possible in the context of the question. There are many things that a specific processor architecture "might have", including some sort of internal memory for storing frequently used constants with dedicated addressing scheme (not that different from x86 FPU register stack, BTW). And there are many things a clever compiler can do, like noticing that constant `6` can be obtained from constant `5` by an `inc` instruction).

Comment: The question, as I interpreted it, is really about how to make or encourage C language compiler to really treat constants as constants.